# wacom intuos4 ring function assignment

Tags: wacom

On  Ubuntu 14.04, I want to assign keystrokes to the left ring wheel. I am able to assign keystrokes to the buttons from system settings, but the ring pads do not respond.

On Ms windows this is pretty straight forward, Is there a utility I can download that will allow this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no utility that will do this in a satisfactory way that I'm aware of. However, you can use xsetwacom on the command-line to solve your problem, cfr. ["Configuring Wacom Tablet buttons and options"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183354/configuring-wacom-tablet-buttons-and-options). It's easier than it looks at first hand.